# SDL with C++ calling Fortran: Scope and Initializer error

Tags: c++, fortran, extern

I want to call a calculation from an older Fortran program but show me the results in a C++-SDL-routine.

Now I have read all the questions here concerning that, but somehow after following all regulations I still get compiler errors.

The relevant code-snippets are as follows:

**SDL_wrapper.h:**

```
extern "C++" void __stdcall callSomeFortran_();
```

**SDL_wrapper.cpp:**

```
#include "/usr/include/SDL/SDL.h"
#include "/usr/include/SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL_wrapper.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   callSomeFortran(); 

    SDL_Surface *screen;
    (...)
```

**fortranFunctions.f90:**

```
subroutine callSomeFortran() bind(C)

    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none 

    write(*,*) 'Were in Fortran!'

end subroutine callSomeFortran
```

Now when I don't call `callSomeFortran()` in main, I can perfectly compile with

**makefile**

```
FLAGS = -lSDL -lstdc++

fortranFunctions: fortranFunctions.o wrapper.o
    gfortran -o fortranFunctions wrapper.o fortranFunctions.o $(FLAGS)

fortranFunctions.o: fortranFunctions.f90
    gfortran -c fortranFunctions.f90 -ffree-line-length-none -o fortranFunctions.o
```

But as I of course want to call that function I include it and get the following errors:

```
In file included from SDL_wrapper.cpp:5:0:
SDL_wrapper.h:1:29: error: expected initializer before ‘callSomeFortran_’
SDL_wrapper.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
SDL_wrapper.cpp:20:20: error: ‘callSomeFortran’ was not declared in this scope
```

I really don't get it. From all the previous posts I've studied, this should work. Also I've already some years coding experience and don't get where there should be a problem with scope.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Well, I have to tell the compiler that it's an external function, therefore I have to declare it, I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extern "C++" void __stdcall callSomeFortran_();
```

is wrong.

1. You declared it in Fortran as

   ```
   callSomeFortran() bind(C)
   ```

the `bind(C)` means (not only) that no trailing underscore will be appended, you should not append it in C++ either. It is better to write it explicitly as `bind(C,name="callSomeFortran")`

2. I don't see any reason for `__stdcall`, I think you are using the default calling conventions.
3. It should be `extern "C"{}`, not `"C++"`. You want it to have C linkage.

Both `extern "C"` and `bind(C)` do a very similar thing. Force the procedure to follow simple C calling conventions. That means that for both Fortran and C++ that the symbol for the procedure will be the name of the function without any change. For Fortran it also means that all variables will be passed using a pointer to them unless declared as `value`.

Without `bind(C)` the name of the symbol would have `_` appended, but this behaviour somewhat differs from compiler to compiler. Also, for module procedures it is more complicated.

Without `extern "C"` the name of the symbol expected would be quite complicated and the rules are also not standardized.

Comment: Holy crap, 1.) and 3.) solved it. I really don't understand though, why some other examples didn't even use bind(C)... could you elaborate when and why I need that? Same goes for "C"{}... Why do I want the C linkage?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborations. My calls work fine now!

Comment: Also note that `__stdcall` is almost certainly wrong too, if there is no `STDCALL` on the Fortran side. It is ingnored on Linux, but it can cause problems on Windows.

Comment: Ok. There's obviously still a big world out there full of linked traps.